# Hudson: "missing the Extended Read permission"

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I log into hudson as an admin but the left hand column remain the same as a normal non-admin user. I have tried -

- Delete the account and create new one with all the admin rights.
- delete all cookies
- Tried on different browsers
- Type in the link for the configuration page, which throw a "missing the ExtendedRead permission" error.

None of the above work, anyone have any suggestion on the issue?

Comment: 'Admin' as in configure an account within Hudson as an Admin or as in I am in the local admin group of my OS and expect that Hudson will actually find that out. If it is the latter, than you are mistaken.

Comment: Admin as an Hudson admin(configured an account in Hudson), nothing to do with OS admin.

Comment: good, excludes one error possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put together what I now so far. Please fill the baps if there are any.

- You use the Extended Read Permission Plugin
- Configured a user in Hudson. Do you use "Hudson's own user database" than or something else?
- The plugin description says it adds a column to the "Matrix-based security" or "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy" authorization stream. Do you use one of these two?

Now I am getting confused about what you are missing for an Admin. I use the "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy". When I am configured only with the global administration permission. I have full control over Hudson and all jobs running on Hudson.

To be able to help you, please describe you setup as it pertains to the authorization settings in detail. Do you have other plugins installed that might interfere here?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply, for our hudson, we manage the security by ticking the enable security. Then in access control, --> authorization, we used Matrix-based security and we then set the authorization of individual user in there. I don't think anything else would interfere with the setting. Thank you very much

Comment: Ok, your problem is know, that you have a user. you checked the admin column for this user, but you didn't see the menus for admin (e.g. manage Hudson or configure job)? Did I state your problem correct?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what happening now. Do you have any idea what that is?

Comment: I guess when you double check the config the admins still have admin the admin permission. So I would try to give them the extended read permission as well. May be that makes a difference. -- If not, there are more questions. Did the extended read plugin ever worked for you or did you just installed it? If you used it successful before, did anything happened to hudson, when this problem occured (Hudson update, new plugin, plugin update)? IF nothing, did anything change on the server (new Hardware, update to OS or other software, ....(continued in next comment)

Comment: ....change of the java version, additional services, that run on that server)? Do you have a backup from before the time that issue occurred? Can you reproduce the issue on another (may be simpler setup)? I almost forgot, if that is the attempt to get the extended read permission plugin to work, than it might just be that the plugin was written for an older version and diesn't work anymore (the plugin description page doesn't look inviting, no release for 1 year) might be unsupported. If you don't get it to run, submit a bug report at http://issues.hudson-ci.org/

Comment: Just remembered something else. Check the Hudson logfiles!